# Map java.util.Map field with MyBatis

Tags: java, dictionary, mybatis

I would like to map data to `java.util.Map` attribute with MyBatis. I have simple POJOs like this:

```
public class Bar {
     ...fields
}

public class Foo {
    private Map<String, Bar> bars;

   public Foo() {
        bars = new HashMap<String, Bar>();
   }

   ...

}
```

How can I map data to bars with MyBatis? Example below doesn't work because it sets always new map to field.

```
<resultMap id="fooResultMap" type="Foo">
   ...attributes
    <association property="bars" resultMap="barResultMap" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="barResultMap" type="map">
        <result property="key" column="bar_key" />
  <association property="value" javaType="Bar">
    ...attributes
  </association>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Should the resultMap in fooResultMap's association be pointing to barResultMap, rather than priceMapResultMap?  I don't understand what part "Price" plays in your question.  You want to fill Foo with many Bars as a map, rather than a List, right?

Comment: Hi thanks that was typo, I corrected it. You right I want to fill Foo with many Bars as a map, rather than a List but can't get it work correctly.

Comment: OK, so next questions - 1) is there a 1:many relationship between foos and bars in the database? (1 Foo can have many Bars)?  2) In your SQL for the mapping are you pulling both back in a single query? 3) When you say it doesn't work because "it sets always new map to field" do you mean it is overwriting the "bars" map you created in the Foo constructor - is it otherwise returning a map or what is it currently returning?

Comment: 1) Yes it is 1:many relationship - Foo can have N (0..*) Bars. 2) Yep I select everything in one query. 3) As I understand MyBatis if I use <association property="bars"... I set new Map for every row so yes It's overwriting map I've created in Foo constructor. And finally yes it is map but with only one Bar (always the last one). I think I need something similar tag like `<collection>` for maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some research on this and asked on the MyBatis Google group, as I'd be interested in how to do this myself.

At the current time, this appears to not be possible. You can easily make it work if you want a `List<Bar>` in the Foo object using the `<collection>` mapping.

I tried using `<collection>` to return a Map, but it doesn't understand what I'm asking it to do.

The only way I know to do this right now is to manage it yourself with two queries/mappings - one to populate Foo with all its fields *other than* its collection of Bars.  Then a query mapping like the one listed below to pull back all Bars in a Map and plug that into your Foo object yourself:

```
@Select("SELECT bar_id, bar_name FROM bar WHERE foo_id = #{id}")
@MapKey("bar_name")
Map<String, Bar> getBarsById(int id);
```

This will return a Map with one entry for each bar, where the key to the entry is the value of the "bar_name" column.

The MyBatis team recommended putting in an issue request for this feature in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for your research. I've also made my own but not figured out anything better. I've end up with building map in java code. If you can post the link to feature request it could be nice. Maybe it can help someone latter on.

Answer (score -10):

About MyBatis and HashMap , that is effectively what it is.

HashMap class implements Map . **Map is an inteface**

therefore **because HashMap implements Map  ,  HashMap IS a Map.**

Whether you use generics key,value on the end of it or not also.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html